# does the Xcode interface builder create a file and if so where is the file located

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I would like to see code that is generated by interface builder.  Hope to learn to make changes to layout by changes code if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't create a source language (C, Swift...) file, if that's what you mean.  It uses XML to save a description of your design and then creates a group of objects from a "compiled" version of that when it's loaded at run time.  You can open a storyboard or xib as source to see the intermediate form.

Answer (score 0):

You create the file (via Xcode's File menu, look for `File` -> `New` -> `File...`) and when that sheet comes up, you can select the kind of Interface Builder file you want (storyboard, xib file, etc.)  For Xcode 8, it'll look like this:

[image: Interface Builder File]

When you create the file, it will appear in your Xcode project's file browser.

If you want to view the XML contents of that file, control click on the `.xib` or `.storyboard` file in the Navigator (the list of files and folders along the left side of the Xcode IDE window) and you'll see something like "`Open As...` which has a submenu choice of "`Source Code`".

You'll quickly realize it's way easier to manipulate these objects using Interface Builder instead of trying to get correctly balanced syntax in XML.